# why setlargeIcon does not work?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.4-kitkat

I created my notification like this

```
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                .setTicker("ticher")
                                .setContentTitle("title")
                                .setContentText("text")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_email)
                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_disturb))
                                .setAutoCancel(false)
                                .build();
```

But setLargeIcon does not work. Large icon of notification is always app icon.

I don't know why. thanks for your help.

Comment: I find this:15:36:18.971: D/RemoteViews(774): RemoteViews parcel: android.os.Parcel@438c88a0 bitmapCache: null

Comment: my device is 4.4.2(19).

Comment: Also doesn't work. Language error.

Comment: This can work well in Nexus(AOSP). Because of special android os(MIUI), this did not work.